# What is evolved faster, ANN+Genetic Algorithms or NEAT?

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm making a cube learn to jump a jumprope by itself, and I don't know what approach would evolve to the most fitness, the fastest.

One approach could be setting up a basic feed-forward ANN with 1 hidden layer only, and tweaking the weights with a genetic algorithm.

On the other hand, another possibility would be to implement NEAT (genetic algorithm can change the number of connection and nodes, as well as the weights in the network).

Since the second approach is obviously more complicated, would it take more time to evolve the neural network than the one with a fixed structure?

Also, does it apply to all cases? For instance, I believe that for a basic jump rope, the basic neural network would do just fine.

Comment: This question is better suited for Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Power of NEAT is in flexibile structure. NEAT takes more time than convention neuro-evolution(optimiznig weights using GA). Is there any special reason(e.c. reinforcment learning) for using GA instead of gradient based methods?

Comment: @viceriel I'm not quite sure how can I use a gradient when I don't have training data. I can only use the fitness function. I'm still learning so if I could use a gradient to solve the problem described, feel free to post an answer.

Comment: You have right. There is reinforcement version of gradient algorithm, but there are less effective than EA, so good pick.